# Retrieving Nested Object from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have pulled an object from my MongoDB database using redux and passing it into the component using props.  I am able to console log where the object is, but not retrieve any of the information within the object.  My goal is to take some of the information from the object and display it using react-bootstrap-table2.

This is what I am getting from the console log

[This is what is showing in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeI7N.png)

This is what I am trying

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    class CurrentTable extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();    
      }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;
    console.log({ items });

    const dig = this.props.item.items[0];
    console.log(dig);

    const columns = [{
      dataField: 'items[0].team',
      text: 'Team',
      sort: true
    }, {
      dataField: 'item.current_Rank',
      text: 'Current Rank',
      sort: true
    }, {
      dataField: 'item.new_Rank',
      text: '321 Rank',
      sort: true
    }];


    return (
      <BootstrapTable 
        keyField="team" 
        data={items} 
        columns={columns}
        striped
        hover />


    )
  }
}

CurrentTable.propTypes = {
  getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ getItems })(CurrentTable);
```

.........
Updated Code:

```
      render() {

    const { items } = this.props.item;
    // console.log({ items });

    const dig = this.props.item.items[0];
    console.log(dig);

    // react - bootstrap - table - next
    const columns = [{
      dataField: 'team',
      text: 'Team',
      sort: true,
      formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
        Object.values(row.team)[rowIndex]                      
      )      
    }, {
      dataField: 'current_Rank',
      text: 'Current Rank',
      sort: true,
      formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
        Object.values(row.current_Rank)[rowIndex]
      )      
    }, {
      dataField: 'new_Rank',
      text: '321 Rank',
      sort: true,
      formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
        Object.values(row.new_Rank)[rowIndex]
      )
    }];

    return (
      <BootstrapTable 
        keyField="team"
        data={items}  
        columns={columns}
        striped
        hover />   

    )
  }
}
```

.... Data:

```
{
"team": {
    "TB": "Tampa Bay Lightning",
    "CAL": "Calgary Flames",
    "BOS": "Boston Bruins",
    "WAS": "Washington Capitals",
    "NYI": "New York Islanders",
    "TOR": "Toronto Maple Leafs",
    "SJ": "San Jose Sharks",
    "NAS": "Nashville Predators",
    "CAR": "Carolina Hurricanes",
    "PIT": "Pittsburgh Penguins",
    "WPG": "Winnipeg Jets",
    "STL": "St. Louis Blues",
    "CBJ": "Columbus Blue Jackets",
    "MTL": "Montreal Canadiens",
    "VGK": "Vegas Golden Knights",
    "DAL": "Dallas Stars",
    "COL": "Colorado Avalanche",
    "PHO": "Arizona Coyotes",
    "MIN": "Minnesota Wild",
    "FLO": "Florida Panthers",
    "PHI": "Philadelphia Flyers",
    "CHI": "Chicago Blackhawks",
    "ANA": "Anaheim Ducks",
    "VAN": "Vancouver Canucks",
    "EDM": "Edmonton Oilers",
    "NYR": "New York Rangers",
    "BUF": "Buffalo Sabres",
    "NJD": "New Jersey Devils",
    "DET": "Detroit Red Wings",
    "LA": "Los Angeles Kings",
    "OTT": "Ottawa Senators"
},
"wins": {
    "TB": 62,
    "CAL": 50,
    "BOS": 49,
    "WAS": 48,
    "NYI": 48,
    "TOR": 46,
    "SJ": 46,
    "NAS": 47,
    "CAR": 46,
    "PIT": 44,
    "WPG": 47,
    "STL": 45,
    "CBJ": 47,
    "MTL": 44,
    "VGK": 43,
    "DAL": 43,
    "COL": 38,
    "PHO": 39,
    "MIN": 37,
    "FLO": 36,
    "PHI": 37,
    "CHI": 36,
    "ANA": 35,
    "VAN": 35,
    "EDM": 35,
    "NYR": 32,
    "BUF": 33,
    "NJD": 31,
    "DET": 32,
    "LA": 31,
    "OTT": 29
},
"loss": {
    "TB": 16,
    "CAL": 25,
    "BOS": 24,
    "WAS": 26,
    "NYI": 27,
    "TOR": 28,
    "SJ": 27,
    "NAS": 29,
    "CAR": 29,
    "PIT": 26,
    "WPG": 30,
    "STL": 28,
    "CBJ": 31,
    "MTL": 30,
    "VGK": 32,
    "DAL": 32,
    "COL": 30,
    "PHO": 35,
    "MIN": 36,
    "FLO": 32,
    "PHI": 37,
    "CHI": 34,
    "ANA": 37,
    "VAN": 36,
    "EDM": 38,
    "NYR": 36,
    "BUF": 39,
    "NJD": 41,
    "DET": 40,
    "LA": 42,
    "OTT": 47
},
"overtime_Loss": {
    "TB": 4,
    "CAL": 7,
    "BOS": 9,
    "WAS": 8,
    "NYI": 7,
    "TOR": 8,
    "SJ": 9,
    "NAS": 6,
    "CAR": 7,
    "PIT": 12,
    "WPG": 5,
    "STL": 9,
    "CBJ": 4,
    "MTL": 8,
    "VGK": 7,
    "DAL": 7,
    "COL": 14,
    "PHO": 8,
    "MIN": 9,
    "FLO": 14,
    "PHI": 8,
    "CHI": 12,
    "ANA": 10,
    "VAN": 11,
    "EDM": 9,
    "NYR": 14,
    "BUF": 10,
    "NJD": 10,
    "DET": 10,
    "LA": 9,
    "OTT": 6
},
"shoot_Out_Wins": {
    "TB": 6,
    "CAL": 0,
    "BOS": 2,
    "WAS": 4,
    "NYI": 5,
    "TOR": 0,
    "SJ": 0,
    "NAS": 4,
    "CAR": 2,
    "PIT": 2,
    "WPG": 2,
    "STL": 3,
    "CBJ": 2,
    "MTL": 3,
    "VGK": 3,
    "DAL": 1,
    "COL": 2,
    "PHO": 4,
    "MIN": 1,
    "FLO": 3,
    "PHI": 3,
    "CHI": 3,
    "ANA": 3,
    "VAN": 6,
    "EDM": 3,
    "NYR": 6,
    "BUF": 5,
    "NJD": 3,
    "DET": 3,
    "LA": 3,
    "OTT": 0
},
"overtime_Wins": {
    "TB": 7,
    "CAL": 5,
    "BOS": 9,
    "WAS": 5,
    "NYI": 6,
    "TOR": 6,
    "SJ": 8,
    "NAS": 5,
    "CAR": 5,
    "PIT": 5,
    "WPG": 7,
    "STL": 6,
    "CBJ": 8,
    "MTL": 4,
    "VGK": 4,
    "DAL": 6,
    "COL": 3,
    "PHO": 5,
    "MIN": 3,
    "FLO": 7,
    "PHI": 6,
    "CHI": 9,
    "ANA": 5,
    "VAN": 7,
    "EDM": 8,
    "NYR": 3,
    "BUF": 7,
    "NJD": 4,
    "DET": 9,
    "LA": 6,
    "OTT": 6
},
"true_Wins": {
    "TB": 49,
    "CAL": 45,
    "BOS": 38,
    "WAS": 39,
    "NYI": 37,
    "TOR": 40,
    "SJ": 38,
    "NAS": 38,
    "CAR": 39,
    "PIT": 37,
    "WPG": 38,
    "STL": 36,
    "CBJ": 37,
    "MTL": 37,
    "VGK": 36,
    "DAL": 36,
    "COL": 33,
    "PHO": 30,
    "MIN": 33,
    "FLO": 26,
    "PHI": 28,
    "CHI": 24,
    "ANA": 27,
    "VAN": 22,
    "EDM": 24,
    "NYR": 23,
    "BUF": 21,
    "NJD": 24,
    "DET": 20,
    "LA": 22,
    "OTT": 23
},
"new_Record": {
    "TB": "49-13-4-16",
    "CAL": "45-5-7-25",
    "BOS": "38-11-9-24",
    "WAS": "39-9-8-26",
    "NYI": "37-11-7-27",
    "TOR": "40-6-8-28",
    "SJ": "38-8-9-27",
    "NAS": "38-9-6-29",
    "CAR": "39-7-7-29",
    "PIT": "37-7-12-26",
    "WPG": "38-9-5-30",
    "STL": "36-9-9-28",
    "CBJ": "37-10-4-31",
    "MTL": "37-7-8-30",
    "VGK": "36-7-7-32",
    "DAL": "36-7-7-32",
    "COL": "33-5-14-30",
    "PHO": "30-9-8-35",
    "MIN": "33-4-9-36",
    "FLO": "26-10-14-32",
    "PHI": "28-9-8-37",
    "CHI": "24-12-12-34",
    "ANA": "27-8-10-37",
    "VAN": "22-13-11-36",
    "EDM": "24-11-9-38",
    "NYR": "23-9-14-36",
    "BUF": "21-12-10-39",
    "NJD": "24-7-10-41",
    "DET": "20-12-10-40",
    "LA": "22-9-9-42",
    "OTT": "23-6-6-47"
},
"points": {
    "TB": 177,
    "CAL": 152,
    "BOS": 145,
    "WAS": 143,
    "NYI": 140,
    "TOR": 140,
    "SJ": 139,
    "NAS": 138,
    "CAR": 138,
    "PIT": 137,
    "WPG": 137,
    "STL": 135,
    "CBJ": 135,
    "MTL": 133,
    "VGK": 129,
    "DAL": 129,
    "COL": 123,
    "PHO": 116,
    "MIN": 116,
    "FLO": 112,
    "PHI": 110,
    "CHI": 108,
    "ANA": 107,
    "VAN": 103,
    "EDM": 103,
    "NYR": 101,
    "BUF": 97,
    "NJD": 96,
    "DET": 94,
    "LA": 93,
    "OTT": 87
},
"current_Points": {
    "TB": 128,
    "CAL": 107,
    "BOS": 107,
    "WAS": 104,
    "NYI": 103,
    "TOR": 100,
    "SJ": 101,
    "NAS": 100,
    "CAR": 99,
    "PIT": 100,
    "WPG": 99,
    "STL": 99,
    "CBJ": 98,
    "MTL": 96,
    "VGK": 93,
    "DAL": 93,
    "COL": 90,
    "PHO": 86,
    "MIN": 83,
    "FLO": 86,
    "PHI": 82,
    "CHI": 84,
    "ANA": 80,
    "VAN": 81,
    "EDM": 79,
    "NYR": 78,
    "BUF": 76,
    "NJD": 72,
    "DET": 74,
    "LA": 71,
    "OTT": 64
},
"current_Rank": {
    "TB": 1,
    "CAL": 2.5,
    "BOS": 2.5,
    "WAS": 4,
    "NYI": 5,
    "TOR": 8,
    "SJ": 6,
    "NAS": 8,
    "CAR": 11,
    "PIT": 8,
    "WPG": 11,
    "STL": 11,
    "CBJ": 13,
    "MTL": 14,
    "VGK": 15.5,
    "DAL": 15.5,
    "COL": 17,
    "PHO": 18.5,
    "MIN": 21,
    "FLO": 18.5,
    "PHI": 22,
    "CHI": 20,
    "ANA": 24,
    "VAN": 23,
    "EDM": 25,
    "NYR": 26,
    "BUF": 27,
    "NJD": 29,
    "DET": 28,
    "LA": 30,
    "OTT": 31
},
"new_Rank": {
    "TB": 1,
    "CAL": 2,
    "BOS": 3,
    "WAS": 4,
    "NYI": 5.5,
    "TOR": 5.5,
    "SJ": 7,
    "NAS": 8.5,
    "CAR": 8.5,
    "PIT": 10.5,
    "WPG": 10.5,
    "STL": 12.5,
    "CBJ": 12.5,
    "MTL": 14,
    "VGK": 15.5,
    "DAL": 15.5,
    "COL": 17,
    "PHO": 18.5,
    "MIN": 18.5,
    "FLO": 20,
    "PHI": 21,
    "CHI": 22,
    "ANA": 23,
    "VAN": 24.5,
    "EDM": 24.5,
    "NYR": 26,
    "BUF": 27,
    "NJD": 28,
    "DET": 29,
    "LA": 30,
    "OTT": 31
},
"conference": {
    "TB": "Eastern",
    "CAL": "Western",
    "BOS": "Eastern",
    "WAS": "Eastern",
    "NYI": "Eastern",
    "TOR": "Eastern",
    "SJ": "Western",
    "NAS": "Western",
    "CAR": "Eastern",
    "PIT": "Eastern",
    "WPG": "Western",
    "STL": "Western",
    "CBJ": "Western",
    "MTL": "Eastern",
    "VGK": "Western",
    "DAL": "Western",
    "COL": "Western",
    "PHO": "Western",
    "MIN": "Western",
    "FLO": "Eastern",
    "PHI": "Eastern",
    "CHI": "Western",
    "ANA": "Western",
    "VAN": "Western",
    "EDM": "Western",
    "NYR": "Eastern",
    "BUF": "Eastern",
    "NJD": "Eastern",
    "DET": "Eastern",
    "LA": "Western",
    "OTT": "Eastern"
},
"division": {
    "TB": "Atlantic",
    "CAL": "Pacific",
    "BOS": "Atlantic",
    "WAS": "Metropolitan",
    "NYI": "Metropolitan",
    "TOR": "Atlantic",
    "SJ": "Pacific",
    "NAS": "Central",
    "CAR": "Metropolitan",
    "PIT": "Metropolitan",
    "WPG": "Central",
    "STL": "Central",
    "CBJ": "Metropolitan",
    "MTL": "Atlantic",
    "VGK": "Pacific",
    "DAL": "Central",
    "COL": "Central",
    "PHO": "Western",
    "MIN": "Central",
    "FLO": "Atlantic",
    "PHI": "Metropolitan",
    "CHI": "Central",
    "ANA": "Pacific",
    "VAN": "Pacific",
    "EDM": "Pacific",
    "NYR": "Metropolitan",
    "BUF": "Atlantic",
    "NJD": "Metropolitan",
    "DET": "Atlantic",
    "LA": "Pacific",
    "OTT": "Atlantic"
}
```

}

[What is resulting on the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHkAc.png)

........Update to code 2.......

```
render() {

let items = this.props.item || {};
// console.log(items);


let dig = this.props.item.items[0] || {};
console.log(typeof(dig));

let teams = dig.team || {};
let current_Rank = dig.current_Rank || {};
let new_Rank = dig.new_Rank || {};
let new_Record = dig.new_Record || {};
let current_Points = dig.current_Points || {};
let points = dig.points || {};
let conference = dig.conference || {};
let division = dig.division || {};
// console.log(Object.values(teams));

// react - bootstrap - table - next
const columns = [
  {
  dataField: 'team',
  text: 'Team',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(teams)[rowIndex]
  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'current_Rank',
  text: 'Current Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(current_Rank)[rowIndex]
  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'new_Rank',
  text: '321 Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(new_Rank)[rowIndex]
  )
  }, {
    dataField: 'new_Record',
    text: 'Record',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(new_Record)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'current_Points',
    text: 'Current Point Total',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(current_Points)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'points',
    text: 'New Point Total',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(points)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'conference',
    text: 'Conference',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(conference)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'division',
    text: 'Division',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(division)[rowIndex]
    )
  }];

return (
  <Container>
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField="team"
      data={dig}
      columns={columns}
      noDataIndication="Table is Empty"
      striped
      hover />   

  </Container>


)
```

.....Update 4....

```
render() {

// let {items} = this.props.item || {};
// console.log({items});


const dig = this.props.item.items[0] || {};
console.log(dig);

let teams = dig.team || {};
let current_Ranks = dig.current_Rank || {};
let new_Ranks = dig.new_Rank || {};
let new_Records = dig.new_Record || {};
let current_Pointss = dig.current_Points || {};
let pointss = dig.points || {};
let conferences = dig.conference || {};
let divisions = dig.division || {};
// console.log(Object.values(teams));

// react - bootstrap - table - next
const columns = [
  {
  dataField: "teams",
  text: 'Team',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(teams)[rowIndex]

  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'current_Rank',
  text: 'Current Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(current_Ranks)[rowIndex]
  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'new_Rank',
  text: '321 Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(new_Ranks)[rowIndex]
  )
  }, {
    dataField: 'new_Record',
    text: 'Record',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(new_Records)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'current_Points',
    text: 'Current Point Total',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(current_Pointss)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'points',
    text: 'New Point Total',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(pointss)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'conference',
    text: 'Conference',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(conferences)[rowIndex]
    )
  }, {
    dataField: 'division',
    text: 'Division',
    sort: true,
    formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
      Object.values(divisions)[rowIndex]
    )
  }];




return (

  <Container>
    <BootstrapTable
      keyField="team"
      data={[dig]}
      columns={columns}
      striped  
      hover />   

  </Container>


)
```

[Result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uitX7.png)

Comment: "My goal is to take some of the information from the object and display it" Which information do you want to get from the object?

Comment: Each object is a column I'd like to display with keys for each team.  For example, I'd like to show the team, their rank, and how many points.  Therefore the three headers of the table would be Team, Rank, Points.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an object of objects, not an array. So, when you want to access a property, you need to use `['the_key']`.
In your case, all the objects inside your data object have the same values, for example `TB,CAL, BOS...`.
So, what you can do, is to retrieve the keys of one of the objects inside your data, for example the `team` object. And that will be an array containing on each index a key. Then if you cant to know the rank of one of those values in the array you could do `this.data.rank[keysArray[0]]`.

Im providing you a working example, please read carefully the TableComponent.js file.

https://codesandbox.io/s/64xlk3rp9z

Comment: Hi thanks for the advise, I tried adding the formatter, but got the following error...Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {TB, CAL, BOS, WAS, NYI, TOR, SJ, NAS, CAR, PIT, WPG, STL, CBJ, MTL, VGK, DAL, COL, PHO, MIN, FLO, PHI, CHI, ANA, VAN, EDM, NYR, BUF, NJD, DET, LA, OTT}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Did you try to use: `{row.team['CB']}`. The team attribute is an object. If you want it as an array you could try `Object.keys(row.team)`, the problem with that is that you need to know by index the team of a certain row

Comment: My goal is to create a table with all the information in the table linked by the index... this is the link to the deployed cite, if you want all the data is in the console.https://nhl-321-pointsystem.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Try to keep the formatter, and try this: `<p>{{Object.keys(row.team)[0]}}` and see what you got. That will convert all the object to an array including only the values. But I see your JS data and the all the item keys are in the same position, for example TB is always at the first position

Comment: So to fill the rest of the spaces for the teams should I just loop through all the teams? for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
  {Object.keys(row.team)[i]};
}

Comment: No, actually you will only need to add an extra parameter to the formatter. https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatter-function. `The `rowIndex` and simply `<p>{{Object.keys(row.team)[rowIndex]}}`

Comment: So I did that, but I am still only getting the first value; TB....formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
        <p>{Object.keys(row.team)[rowIndex]}</p>
              
      )... Also I need what the key is connected to for example TB: "Tampa Bay Lightning"

Comment: So I switched keys to values... therefore I got the values I need. But I am still having the issues of not all the rows filling out.  All I get is the first value

Comment: Please update your code above and also paste a sample data in JSON format so I can help you with a working sample.

Comment: @ngeary2193 edit you question, not this answer post. Your edit here should soon be rejected.

Comment: @ngeary2193 ".Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child" I suggest you google this error message. There is at least one answer to this on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: Thank you @Code-Apprentice.  I believe I got past that point when I changed the formatter to include Object.values(row.team)[rowIndex].  My problem now is that it only is coming up as one row, with the first value.  Also if I take out the [rowIndex] all the information shows up in one row.

Comment: I assume that you want a row in the table to show the info for a single team. To get there, I think the first step is to turn your current object into an array of objects, one for each team.

Comment: So I should form the data by team (each row) instead of by stat (columns)

Comment: Hey, I edited my solution, please check the working example I attached you, please, read entirely the TableComponent.js file.

Comment: @JacoboTapia Hey thanks for the update.  I am still getting the following error. TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. when i create the keys... const keys = Object.keys(this.props.item.items[0]);

Comment: You don’t need to do that. You only have to do items.team for example. Remember, you’re using an object, not an array so [0]  does not exists. You could never access any object like an array, you need to use the key. Also, according to your data .items inside .item does not exists.

Comment: const keys = Object.keys(this.props.items.team);
    console.log(keys).... and then I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'team' of undefined

Comment: Why are you declaring the item inside curly braces? Did you try to do it without them? Please try to do Object.keys(this.props.item.team);

Comment: When I don't add the braces, the data doesn't get to the array.  I am not sure why.

Comment: Try to retrieve it like this.props.item.items.team.

Comment: So a small update... I was able to create each column as it's own object by changing the following. let dig = this.props.item.items[0] || {};  this issue was that it took time for the component to mount and the data to be retrieved into the array.... but I am still having the same issue with only one row showing in the table... and it wont let me connect the data for the table to the dig object I created... I get the following errors Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `DataProvider`, expected `array`. even though when I use the typeof function I get an object

Comment: updated code above.. Also this error TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: Again, I don’t understand why you’re trying this let dig = this.props.item.items[0]. Items is not an array, is a dictionary. When you do the [0] you’re not getting all the elements, just one. That’s why on my solution I do the Object.keys(this.props.item.items.team) and use that as my data, just to have an array that can be iterable and with the key to each information of an element along all the objects (teamName, score, etc)

Comment: the [0] is the array first array that is getting pulled into items. therefore all the arrays with team names and other stats are arrays within that [0] array... it still doesn't explain why only the first row is showing... if I set the rowIndex to another number then it changes, but still only in that first row

Comment: Ok so why don't you add an extra variable `let teams = dig.team || {}; let data = Object.keys(teams)` and use `data` as the data of the bootstrap table?